# Let's play the name game

Tags: riddle, knowledge, movies

> An accident leaves only me and my spherical friend
>   I'm quite the hubristic tricky trickster
>   I break backs and grew up in gloom
>   I'm a pompous member of the snake crew
>   I die a lot to save the world from E.T.s
>   I'm an agent in darkness, but you probably don't remember meeting me

What is my name?

Comment: Men in black?^^

Comment: @MichaSprengers Women in white?^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An accident leaves only me and my spherical friend

> Tom Hanks as Chuck Noland in "Castaway"

I'm quite the hubristic tricky trickster

> Tom Hiddleston as Loki in "Thor"

I break backs and grew up in gloom

> Tom Hardy as Bane in Batman: The Dark Knight Rises

I'm a pompous member of the snake crew

> Tom Felton as Draco Malfoy in the Harry Potter movies

I die a lot to save the world from E.T.s

> (original answerer's answer)Tom Baker as The Fourth Doctor in Dr. Who
>  (question poster's intended answer)Tom Cruise as Cage in Edge of Tomorrow

I'm an agent in darkness, but you probably don't remember meeting me

> Tommy Lee Jones as Agent K in Men In Black

Your name is

> Tom

Comment: You are correct!